# How do I refresh my ListView after the Activity launched by "new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION)" finishes?

Tags: java, android

I have a class (`Contacts.java`) that extends `Activity` and has a `TabHost` with 3 children:

```
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabHost.setup(mlam);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    Intent intentA = new Intent().setClass(this, A.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A").setContent(intentA);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    Intent intentB = new Intent().setClass(this, B.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B").setContent(intentB);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    Intent intentC = new Intent().setClass(this, C.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C").setContent(intentC);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Each class (A.java, B.java and C.java) shows a different contacts' list. NOTE: I don't use ListActivity, I use an Activity with a ListView.

I have two problems:

1. When I select a contact, I go to another ListActivity (Options.java) with options about the selected contact. Well, when I press back button from Options.java, the previous contacts' list is empty. How can I see the contacts??? I have tried to handle the Back button to return A.class, but instead, it leaves the general application. NOTE: All intents are declared with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
2. I have added one option in menu button in A.class. This option is "add new contact":

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater=new MenuInflater(getApplicationContext());
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
       return true;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {

           case R.id.menu_add_contact:
           Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);                                                      
               addContactIntent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 

               startActivity(addContactIntent);
               break;          
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

How can I wait to finish activity to update the contacts' list with the new contact? I have tried:

- to use finish(); and finishFromChild(A.this); before "break" but it leaves the general application instead of closing only A.class to re-create.
- to use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() with its onActivityResult() but I don't know where put setResult() and finish() because Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION) is a native Intent of Android.
- to refresh the list before "return true" but this is done before add contact.
- I added listener in Contact.class to detect changes and call onResume() method in each child but do nothing:

Contact.class:

```
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            String currentTag = tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
            if(currentTag.equals("A")){
                //intentA.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                mlam.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(intentA));
            } else if(currentTag.equals("B")){
                //intentB.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                mlam.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(intentB));
            }else if(currentTag.equals("C")){
                //intentC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                mlam.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(intentC));
            }
        }
    });*/
```

A.class ...:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //refresh code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult() and override onActivityResult to know when started activity finished

Comment: How can I wait to finish activity to update the contact list with the new contact? I have tried:
    to use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() with its onActivityResult() but I don't know where put setResult() and finish() because it is a native intent of android.

Answer (score 0):

In `Contacts.java` inside `onResume` method re-init all yor lists. So each time you are comming back to `Contacts.java` activity your list of contact are refreshed...

Comment: Inside onResume I have: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        ContactListAdapter adapter2=setAllContacts();
                        list.setAdapter(adapter2);
                        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); and don't work